# How to change font for axes, labels, etc in pgfplots using fontspec (lualatex)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, pgfplots, luatex, fontspec

I need to make figure with `Garamond` font applied to axes and labels, as well to text in `nodes`.

This is my `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
line width=.5 pt,
tick style={line width=.6pt}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip mode=individual,
height=8cm,
width=10cm,
xmin=1.9,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.5,
enlarge x limits=.0,
enlarge y limits=.02,
ylabel={YLABEL},
xlabel={XLABEL},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot[black,dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (3.4,.49)};
\addplot[black,dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (3.44,.44)};

\node[] at (axis cs: 2.7,0.2) {Text with Garamond font 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is output:

[image]

The text in `node` is printed using `Garamond` font, but axes and labels did not change.

What is the simple way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See two marked bits (otherwise the tic labels are set in math mode by default)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}%<=== think you needed this - you presumably have the font locally otherwise

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
line width=.5 pt,
tick style={line width=.6pt}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip mode=individual,
height=8cm,
width=10cm,
xmin=1.9,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.5,
enlarge x limits=.0,
enlarge y limits=.02,
ylabel={YLABEL},
xlabel={XLABEL},
minor x tick num=4,
minor y tick num=4,
tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},%<=== this is what you need
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
]
\addplot[black,dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (3.4,.49)};
\addplot[black,dashed] coordinates {(0,0) (3.44,.44)};

\node[] at (axis cs: 2.7,0.2) {Text with Garamond font 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great also for heat maps and their contour lines, but it seems it doesn't affect  the labels of its colorbar, which is configured in the axis arguments together with `tick label style`.