# Typeset pgfmath number in text mode

Tags: pgfmath, text-mode

Some of the figures I make with `pgfplots` use `pgfmath` to calculate the tick positions for the extrema of a function, with code similar to the one given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/highlighting-extremal-values-in-table/34045#34045).

However, these numbers seem to always be typeset in math mode (I can tell because I'm using oldstyle numerals). I've come across a similar problem when I would normally use `\pgfmathprintnumber`, but find that this is also (understandably) typeset as math by default.

Is there a way to use the `pgfmath` number parsing code, but then typeset that number in text mode?

I can provide a MWE, but I don't know how useful it would be in this case.

Comment: Is `\mathrm{}` what you need?

Comment: Yeah, this works: `$\mathrm{\pgfmathprintnumber{1983.00000000000}}$`. I'll have to figure out how to put that into the `tick style` somehow, but I guess that's a different question. :)

Comment: Yes the MWE would be useful if only to clarify your question -- however see my Answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228396/how-to-change-font-for-axes-labels-etc-in-pgfplots-using-fontspec-lualatex/228401#228401

Comment: I'll try to put together a MWE for this, but these two comments do everything I need. You answer on that other question did what I wanted in the plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of MWE.. you need this rather paradoxical bit

```
begin{axis}[
tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},%<=== here
]
```

Comment: It is rather a shorthand without the bold part `assume` **that you are already in** `math mode`